# How do I use getSource() with a JRadioButton?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

I need to preface this with my instructor won't allow us to use IDE's in class, so I am doing this in textpad. I want to click the raido button and change the "traffic light" color. How do I use getSource() to interact with the radio button?

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;



public class Lab4Frame extends JFrame {

    Lab4Frame(){
        setTitle("Lab 4 - Application #1");
        Lab4Panel p = new Lab4Panel();
        Lab4RadioButtonPanel p2 = new Lab4RadioButtonPanel();
        setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
        add(p);
        add(p2);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

            Lab4Frame frame = new Lab4Frame();
            frame.setTitle("Lab4 Application # 1");
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setSize(600, 600);
            frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}

class Lab4RadioButtonPanel extends JPanel implements MouseListener {

    public Lab4RadioButtonPanel() {

        this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        JRadioButton jrbRed = new JRadioButton("Red", true);
        JRadioButton jrbYellow = new JRadioButton("Yellow");
        JRadioButton jrbGreen = new JRadioButton("Green");
        this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
        ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
        group.add(jrbRed);
        group.add(jrbYellow);
        group.add(jrbGreen);

        this.add(jrbRed);
        this.add(jrbYellow);
        this.add(jrbGreen);

        jrbRed.setMnemonic('E');
        jrbGreen.setMnemonic('G');
        jrbYellow.setMnemonic('Y');
    }




            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
                {
                    if (e.getSource() == jrbRed){

                    }

                    else if (e.getSource() == jrbYellow){

                    }

                    else if (e.getSource() == jrbGreen){

                    }



                }

        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){}
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){}
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){}
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e){}
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e){}
}

class Lab4Panel extends JPanel{


    public Lab4Panel(){
    }



    int height, width;
    int radius = 5;
    int x = -1;
    int y = -1;

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        if (x<0 || y<0) {
            x = getWidth() / 2 - radius;
            y = getHeight() / 2 - radius;
        }
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawRect(x - 10,y - 90, 40, 120);
        //g.drawOval(x,y - 80, 4 * radius, 4 * radius);
        //g.drawOval(x,y - 40, 4 * radius, 4 * radius);
        //g.drawOval(x,y, 4 * radius, 4 * radius);
        g.drawRect(x - 5,y - 90, 40, 120);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillOval(x,y - 80, 4 * radius, 4 * radius);
        g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        g.fillOval(x,y - 40, 4 * radius, 4 * radius);
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.fillOval(x,y, 4 * radius, 4 * radius);

    }


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use a mouse listener with buttons including radio buttons. Use an action listener instead. Also for *any* listener to work, it must be first added to the component.

Comment: Okay, thanks I am not very good at actionlisteners I was hoping to just use mouseClicked

Comment: Read the tutorials on radio buttons as this will likely be explained there.